# Can we read from different type of index to update in another index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Query from one index with conditions to update matched documents in another index (2 different types of indexes). Is it possible in elasticsearch?. Using elasticsearch 7.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific. 
If you want to migrate the same document as-is from one index to another. but filtering those documents to a certain number based on some conditions that are specified in a query. then, Yes! you can do that using the migrate query
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

---

Edited:
If you want to reindex a totally different type of index using a portion of the info from the original index then, I would make a script to query based on some conditions and then bulk insert results into the new index.

Comment: If your documents share the same id between index, it could be possible to use reindex api. If not, it wont be possible.You would have to make a small program.

Comment: I'm talking about 2 different types of indexes.

Comment: Then I would make a script to query based on some conditions and then bulk insert results into the new index.